# How to correctly show a random variable has an exponential distribution?

Tags: probability

If I wanted to show a random variable $X$ is exponential, would it suffice to show its cumulative density function is equivalent to the cdf of an exponential variable with some parameter $\lambda$?

Comment: Yes, as CDF determines a distribution.

Comment: That's fine in a theoretical setting. But if you have data and want to know if they are consistent with exponential, then you need a goodness-of-fit test.